Get current path to get file version
This is probably a simple question but I haven't been able to figure out how to solve it. I just want to get the version of a file in the current directory after downloading it. I know there are about 5 ways to get the file version and none of them work.
  $path = ?
  Move-Item .\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe .\chromedriver.exe -Force  
  $version = (Get-command "$path\chromedriver.exe").FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
  write-host "Chrome is now version: $version"

What do I need to do to get the path? Now the path is on Onedrive and contains a dash in it if that matters.
I've tried using

$pwd
(get-location).path
$PWD | select -Expand Path


You moved the item to the current directory.  Why do you have a path at all?  Just Get-Command chromedriver.exe.

I just looked at the properties of the file and there is no metadata. That's why it isn't showing up. It isn't a powershell issue at all.

That's poor engineering practice.  Any executable released into the wild like this should have a VERSION resource.

There is a -v switch that I used with Start-Process and parsed it out.


Fundamentally, Windows executables are not required to have an embedded version-information resource in order to be valid executables.

Per your own feedback, the absence of such a resource in chromedriver.exe turned out to be the real problem.


Generally, Get-Command looks for a given executable specified by name only in $env:PATH; in order to target an executable in a given directory, you indeed need to specify a path, which may be a relative one.

Therefore, given that you've moved your executable to the current directory, referencing it as .\chromedriver.exe is sufficient in principle (but, as noted, a given executable may lack this information):
# May not produce output for a given executable, such as here.
(Get-Command .\chromedriver.exe).FileVersionInfo.FileVersion


As an aside: Get-Command output objects also have a direct .Version property that reports the version number, and does so as a [version] (System.Version) instance (whereas .FileVersionInfo.FileVersion is a string):
# Reports [version] '0.0.0.0'
# if the executable lacks a version-info resource.
(Get-Command .\chromedriver.exe).Version


However, note that this version number is a synthesized one, that appears to be determined as follows: if the .VersionInfo.ProductVersionRaw is filled in, it is used in lieu of .VersionInfo.FileVersionRaw; these *Raw versions can differ from their non-raw counterparts in their final component: they use the value of .VersionInfo.ProductPrivatePart / .VersionInfo.ProductPrivatePart as their final version component (the revision part).






If a given executable lacks a version-info resource but supports reporting its version via its CLI, typically via a --version option, you can derive the version number from parsing the executable's output.
A simpler alternative to your own answer:
(-split (.\chromedriver.exe --version))[1]

Note:

The solution assumes that it is the 2nd whitespace-separated token in the output that is the version number; adjust accordingly for other executables.

Some executables, such as java.exe, send version information to stderr rather than stdout; in that case, append 2>&1 to the CLI call.

If the extracted version number string is in a format compatible with the [version] (System.Version) class (e.g., '2.3.4'), you can simply prepend a [version] cast to the command above to construct an instance of this type.
In PowerShell (Core) 7, the same applies additionally to [semver] (System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion)



This is what I tried at first. Then I tried with all of the other path tests before realizing they were futile.

Understood, @MattWilliamson. This answer is meant to provide general information to future readers based on your question as asked (even though your real problem turned out to be a different one). It's a good idea to glean the version from the CLI output, as you show in your answer, but you can greatly simplify that: please see my update.

Definitely. @mklement0 I changed my code to that and it's much simpler and works great! I'd definitely prefer to not write out any temp files when possible. I was even looking into System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo to get around it.

This is what I ended up doing
    $Path = Join-Path -Path $(($env:PSModulePath -split(";"))[0]) -ChildPath 'Selenium\3.0.1\assemblies'
    Start-Process '.\chromedriver.exe' -ArgumentList '-v' -RedirectStandardOutput C:\temp\chromedv.txt -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait 
    $version = (-split (get-content -path C:\temp\chromedv.txt))[1]
    remove-item C:\temp\chromedv.txt

While this worked, the update provided by mklement0 of
$version = (-split (.\chromedriver.exe --version))[1]

which also equates to
$version = (-split (.\chromedriver.exe -v))[1]

is what I ended up using. It was much more succinct, didn't require writing and parsing a temp file and way less code.
